# Formatting numbers in Chart Label asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Below binds graph correctly, but values are coming in numbers, we want to show in millions like 250M, 200M (if values is in millions), else show in 100k (if value is in thousand) ... see below

```
  Chart3.DataSource = dt11;
    Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
    Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.LineWidth = 0;
    Chart3.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Amount";
    Chart3.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Acquisition";
    Chart3.DataBind();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize [`LabelStyle.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.labelstyle.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_DataVisualization_Charting_LabelStyle_Format) property to format Y-axis numeric scale as you want:

```
// for numbers up to 1 milion
Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#,##0,k";

// for numbers more than 1 milion & less than 1 billion
Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#,##0,,M";
```

The technique used in code above is called *number scaling specifier*, based from [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/0c899ak8(v=vs.100)#the--custom-specifier-2):

> **Number scaling specifier**: If one or more commas are specified
>   immediately to the left of the explicit or implicit decimal point, the
>   number to be formatted is divided by 1000 for each comma. For example,
>   if the string "0,," is used to format the number 100 million, the
>   output is "100".

Additionally, to enforce the desired format you can use if-condition the check maximum value of the series first, and set maximum scale into [`AxisY.Maximum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of the chart:

```
// assumed dt11 is a DataTable,
// use Compute() method with Max() function to get maximum value of the series
var maxValue = Convert.ToInt32(dt11.Compute("Max([Amount])", string.Empty));
double maxScale;

if (maxValue < 1000000)
{
    Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#,##0,k";

    // set maximum scale to the nearest interval by 500,000
    maxScale = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(maxValue) / 500000d) * 500000;
}
else if (maxValue >= 1000000 && maxValue < 1000000000)
{
    Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#,##0,,M";

    // set maximum scale to the nearest interval by 5 million
    maxScale = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(maxValue) / 5000000d) * 5000000;
}
// other conditions

// set maximum scale
Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.Maximum = maxScale;
```